# plot the histogram of a 1D array in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, scipy

I have a 1D numpy array  h=[h1,h2,h3....hn]
and I created the x=[1,2,3...n] for weights with this

code:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.arange(len(h))
```

I want to plot the histogram, and I don't know how?
thank you.

here is my data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xx02015pbr484es/Book2.xlsx
I want somthing like this:
[image]

Comment: See some easy examples here - http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

Comment: What happens with `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`; `plt.hist(h)`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend `pandas`, which also wraps maplotlib's plot functions and allows you to plot directly using the `DataFrame` object methods:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_excel('Book2.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
df.plot()
```